# Conflicting javascripts

Tags: javascript

I have two javascripts running on my webpage, one to dynamically resize the iframe height based on the content html and another to look up the title of the iframe content page and display it on the parent page. Both provided by other contributors on various forums.

My problem is if I have the iframe title displayed in the parent page code running all I get is a small iframe with vertical scroll bars. You can see this at www.katzxstitch.co.uk/shop (click on to the Terms and Conditions page).

If anyone could help I would be obliged. I am an amateur at html (trying to learn) and a total novice at javascript (also trying to learn).

Regards, Neil.

The javascript is as follows:

**Resizing the iframe to the html content height:**

```
    function getDocHeight(doc) {
    doc = doc || document;
     // stackoverflow.com/questions/1145850/
    var body = doc.body, html = doc.documentElement;
    var height = Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, 
        html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );
    return height;
}

    function setIframeHeight(id) {
    var content_iframe = document.getElementById(id);
    var doc = content_iframe.contentDocument? content_iframe.contentDocument:  content_iframe.contentWindow.document;
    content_iframe.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    content_iframe.style.height = "10px"; // reset to minimal height ...
    // IE opt. for bing/msn needs a bit added or scrollbar appears
    content_iframe.style.height = getDocHeight( doc ) + 4 + "px";
    content_iframe.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

**iframe title displayed in parent page**

```
document.getElementByName('content_iframe')[0].onload = function(){
    document.title = window.frames.content_iframe.document.title;
};
```

Could anyone advise please

Comment: could you provide us a working JSFiddle, or at least post your HTML? Do so and ping me back that I want to take a look at it.